# Compact sets in quotients of topological groups

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation, compactness, topological-groups

The following is proposition 1.6 from chapter XII in the book 'Real and Functional Analysis' by S. Lang.  In this context $G$ is a topological group, $H$ a subgroup and $\pi :G\to G/H$ the quotient map, where $G/H$ is the set of left congruence classes mod $H$.

> If $K'$ is a compact subset of $G/H$, then there exists a compact subset $K$ of $G$ such that $K'=\pi(K)$

Proof. Let $A$ be a compact neighborhood of $e$ in $G$. Then $\pi(A)$ is a compact neighborhood of the unit coset in $G/H$. Let $x_1,\dots,x_n$ be elements of $G$ such that the sets $\pi(x_iA)$ cover $K'$. Let $K=\pi^{-1}(K')\cap (x_1A\cup\dots\cup x_nA)$. Then $K$ is compact and satisfies our requirements.

Questions:

- For the existence of $A$ we need to assume that $G$ is locally compact, right? I think this is also assumed before the proposition but it isn't really stated anywhere.
- Why is $K$ compact? Clearly $x_1A\cup\dots\cup x_nA$ is compact. If $\pi^{-1}(K')$ was closed then $K$ is compact but I don't see why $\pi^{-1}(K')$ should be closed. This should be the case if for example $G/H$ is Hausdorff, i.e. $H$ is closed. But this is not assumed here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. I suppose that Lang is assuming that is groups are locally compact. Note the the title of the chapter is *Integration on locally compact groups*.
2. Since $K'$ is compact, it is closed. So, since $\pi$ is continuous, $\pi^{-1}(K')$ is closed too.

Comment: Ad 2: that's only true in Hausdorff case btw.

Comment: @freakish Indeed. It's only at a later point that Lang assumes that all of his topological groups are Hausdorff, but I think that it is a safe guess that he forget to add that assumption here.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you. But this makes both points confusing, since both points have hidden assumptions. I don't like this frivolous approach to details.

Comment: @freakish Me neither.